# The output language string of java exec()

Tags: java, exec

I'd like to get some of the Windows/Linux command result via Java exec().

This is easily archieved but the language of the output strings are the same as the OS language. I'd like to get the output as English. Is it possbile?

Comment: This is an Operating System question, not a programming question, and is better asked on https://serverfault.com/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to tell the application what locale to use.

- On Linux this is done by setting environment variables in the application's environment.  These are described in various places; e.g. "man locale" and "man bash" (and search for "LANG" and "LC_").
- On Windows ... I don't know ... but I have seen answers that suggest that setting shell-local LANG and LC_* environment variables will work there too.

To do this successfully, you will also need to understand how to set environment variables correctly in a child process.  For example:

```
  ...exec("export LANG=C");
  ...exec("some command");
```

will NOT work.

Note that this approach will only work to the extent that the external application you are trying to run supports internationalized output / error messages.  If it doesn't, there is no magic that will automatically translate the output for you.

Comment: You set the environment variable using [`environment()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#environment--) method of `ProcessBuilder`, so you don't have to use OS / script specific command to set it.

Comment: Yup ... I didn't have time to add that stuff before leaving for work.